# Use password with stream_socket_client in php script

Tags: php, iphone

in my php script that sends a push notification to iPhone, I have the below code.

The SSL certificate requires a password. From the command line, it just asks you for it and you can enter it, but how do I get this script to run automatically without asking for the password? I am happy to have the password hardcoded into my script here

```
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort,
    $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if (!$apns) {
    echo "$errorString($error)<br />\n";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you may find this useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php#85345

Comment: I do beleive that you can remove the passphrase from a SSL certificate. Is this not true?

Comment: @thomasfedb Yes, that's also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of setting the [context option `passphrase`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php). Since you're already passing the stream transport constructor a context, I suppose you know how to do that.